# Torch not finding file in Docker container which there

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, torch, replicate

I'm trying to run the [following repo](https://github.com/rossjillian/cog-controlnet-11), which is basically a Docker container for ControlNet/Stable Diffusion. It's requires me to download the model files first, which I have done, and then you can run the container to generate an image.

Without doing any changes to the repo, I get an error that the `v1-5-pruned.ckpt` file is not found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cog/server/worker.py", line 185, in _setup
run_setup(self._predictor)
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cog/predictor.py", line 49, in run_setup
predictor.setup()
File "predict.py", line 33, in setup
self.canny_model = load_model(canny_model_name)
File "predict.py", line 243, in load_model
torch.load(os.path.abspath('./models/v1-5-pruned.ckpt'))
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 699, in load
with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 230, in _open_file_like
return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode)
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 211, in __init__
super(_open_file, self).__init__(open(name, mode))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/src/models/v1-5-pruned.ckpt'
ⅹ Model setup failed
```

To reproduce this error, simply clone the repo, download the model weights and run a prediction using `cog`.

This is the function that it's failing on:

```
def load_model(name):
    model = create_model(f'./models/{name}.yaml').cpu()
    torch.load(os.path.abspath('./models/v1-5-pruned.ckpt'))
    model.load_state_dict(load_state_dict(f'./models/v1-5-pruned.ckpt', location='cuda'), strict=False)
    model.load_state_dict(load_state_dict(f'./models/{name}.pth', location='cuda'), strict=False)
    model = model.cuda()
    return model
```

Now, I've checked the container and I'm certain the model files are there. I'm assuming the issue is related to the (relative) paths used and them not matching the folder structure. I've tried to change the path in all kinds of ways to get it to point to the right place, but I just can't figure it out.

What's going on here? Does torch load files with a base path different from the rest of the code?